# Endless runner that's vertical AND horizontal?

Tags: cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I'm trying to making a sprite kit game, similar to toss the turtle or flight or learn 2 fly.

Think jetpack joyride, but with no ceiling limit.

How would I do this? How did the programmers of the flash games like toss the turtle, flight, learn 2 fly do it?

A very tall background still won't work because theoretically the player could get that high.

In the average endless runner, the y axis is locked and the moving background repeats creating the illusion of horizontal movement.

I could do the same and lock the x axis too and repeat the backgrounds vertically.

I'm worried this will break the illusion as the player will be completely stationary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to provide us with some code, or google a little to find what exactly you need. Your question is very broad, and therefore lacks the scope required on stack-overflow. Besides, the various games you mentioned may have used different implementations to reach a similar result.

Comment: Well google gives no results for a runner that works in multiple directions. And it's not really a code problem, it's an implementation problem. Do you think the possible solution I said above would work, or would it look fishy? Could you give me an idea of a better way to implement it?

Comment: I think the best way to find that out is to try it first. Once you have something, then you can work on increasing processing efficiency. Repeating backgrounds with locked axes would probably require a tile map. To keep that efficient you might want to manage which are rendered and which are hidden (visible vs. not). If you want a smooth look, you can use advanced scene processing (I described it for you in your other question, which appears to ask something very similar) and center the node on the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question would be better suited for [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) site.

There are a number of solutions to a broad question like this but you already provided a lot of hints for an answer in your question. If your player is able to move freely in any direction, without limits, a pre-made map obviously will not work.

The solution is to have generic seamless map sections. If, for example, your player keeps moving up. You add a row to the current view. When the player reaches the top part of that row, you add another row to the top and remove the bottom most row. Same principal for other directions.

To visualize this, think of the player in the center of 9 map sections. Rows or columns get added and removed dependent on the player's movement.